# How to increase the alive time of session_id in Odoo 11?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

A co-worker of mine is getting through code the Odoo `session_id` when he makes the API request to `/web/session/authenticate`. But he tells me that this `session_id` changes every now and again and he has to repeat the request.

What I did to solve his problem is to modify the method `session_gc`, which is in `odoo/http.py`. In this method there are the following lines:

```
# we keep session one week
last_week = time.time() - 60*60*24*7
```

And I modified them to write this instead:

```
# we keep session six weeks
last_week = time.time() - 60*60*24*7*6
```

I expected to make the `session_id` be alive six weeks, but my co-worker has just told me that it happened again, the `session_id` changed after a week.

Do you have any idea of what could be happening?